# SCNKit: Scaling parent node not working

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to scale down a SCNNode that contains other nodes, but itself has no geometries. I read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408050-scale) on scale, but I'm a little skeptical that they would make positioning relative to the parent, but not scale.

The problem:
`scale` does not seem to do anything.

Here's a snippet of my SCNNode sub-class

```
addChildNode(Node1)
addChildNode(Node2)
Node2.addChildNode(Node21)
addChildNode(Node3)

print("pre-scale", self.scale)
// prints SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0)
self.scale = SCNVector3(x:0.05, y:0.05, z:0.05)
print("post-scale", self.scale)
// prints SCNVector3(x: 0.05, y: 0.05, z: 0.05)
```

Visibly, nothing changes.

I've considered doing a loop and applying the scaling factor to every child node, but I think the relative positions will get all messed up.

I'd like everything to scale as one and retain its integrity. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The scale affects all subnode wether they have a geometry or not just like the position or orientation. Your code above should therefore work fine.

Comment: Hmm, may I ask you to recommend a way to debug this? I'm really having trouble because the printed scale says the correct value, but visually it's the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale all child nodes one by one:

```
let newScale = Float(0.05)
for c in self.childNodes
{
    c.scale = SCNVector3Make(newScale, newScale, newScale)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent node may not assign to any camera. try adding the camera to the node and try the scaling.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

parentNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```